# Add offset to all filenames

Tags: java, file, lambda, file-structure

From all the files in a directory, the method `shiftFilenamesOffset` is to increment the numeric part (int) of the alphanumeric filename by offset each time, and rename the files. A negative offset is also allowed.

Example:

```
offset: -2
Old filename:                  New filename:
Textdokument (neu) 3.txt    -> Textdokument (neu) 1.txt
Textdokument (neu) 5.4.1txt -> Textdokument (neu) 5.2.1txt
Textdokument (neu) 5.txt    -> Textdokument (neu) 3.txt
Textdokument (neu) 6.txt    -> Textdokument (neu) 4.txt
```

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NFiles {
    record Filename(File file, String prefix, int number, String ending) {
    }

    private static final String regex = "(.*)(\\d+)\\.([^.]*)";
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    public static void shiftFilenamesOffset(final File dir, final int offset) {
        Comparator<Filename> filenameComparator = offset <= 0 ? Comparator.comparingInt(Filename::number) : Comparator.comparingInt(Filename::number)
                .reversed();
        Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(dir.listFiles()))
                .filter(f -> pattern.matcher(f.getName()).find())
                .map(f -> {
                    Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(f.getName());
                    mat.find();
                    return new Filename(f, mat.group(1), Integer.parseInt(mat.group(2)), mat.group(3));
                })
                .sorted(filenameComparator)
                .forEach(fn -> {
                    File nf = new File(fn.file().getParent(), fn.prefix() + (fn.number() + offset) + "." + fn.ending());
                    System.out.println(fn + " -> " + nf + " -> " + fn.file().renameTo(nf));
                });
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        shiftFilenamesOffset(new File("test1"), -3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reusing function

You can create a constant with Comparator function and reuse it in method.

```
private static final Comparator<Filename> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Filename::number);
    enter code here

public static void shiftFilenamesOffset(final File dir, final int offset) {
        Comparator<Filename> filenameComparator = offset <= 0 ? comparator : comparator.reversed();
    -----
    -----
        }
```

### Duplicate computation

`pattern.matcher(f.getName()).find()` is done twice and can be done once.
Something like this

```
Arrays.stream(Objects.requireNonNull(dir.listFiles()))
                .map(f -> {
                    Matcher mat = pattern.matcher(f.getName());
                    return mat.find() ? new Filename(f, mat.group(1), Integer.parseInt(mat.group(2)), mat.group(3)) : null;
                })
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
```

### Invariants Validation

You can add Invariants/Input validation at the beginning of method.
Also you've put non null check on `dir.listFiles()` which is good.
`Objects.requireNonNull(dir.listFiles())`

you can add further validation if `dir` or `offset` are valid or not in the beginning.

### Minor Comment

- Rename your constants to match the regular expression '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$' meaning that they should be uppercase separated by underscore generally.

### Good Points In your code

- Used latest Java Features like records.
- Used fluent APIs and streams to iterate over directory structure and using comparator.

Comment: Many thanks for your review @SRJ. I think, the most important points are to check/validate the input parameters, and that there is a duplicate computation, which can be avoided using null return values...

Answer (score 1):

Prefer regex definitions that have comments and named groups.

It's not very helpful to mark function parameters as `final`. `File` and `int` are already immutable, and even if they weren't, it doesn't particularly matter if those are marked `final` because that only prevents referential mutation, not value mutation.

Don't force a match, increment and rename all in one go. Split them out for the purposes of unit testing and dryrun support. Java-like code would represent this as a renaming tool object.

Let the caller decide whether to sort or not, for them to print or test. Only enforce sort (which breaks `Stream` laziness) on rename.

Prefer `Path` manipulation from `nio`.

Fail early. Don't wait until the directory list to check for nulls; instead check that the provided path is actually a directory so that no null check is needed. Also: using the `Files.list` method, the insane return-null behaviour has been replaced with an exception.

You've missed a character in your regex for the negative sign in an ID.

Since the ordering depends on offset, I propose a simpler natural ordering scheme using a nested class and `Comparable<>`.

### Suggested

```java
package com.stackexchange.filename_offset;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


/**
 * A class to rename a collection of files in a given directory by adding a given offset.
 * The natural ordering of the nested Filename class depends on the offset's sign.
 */
public class RenameTool {
    public final Path dir;
    public final int offset;

    public RenameTool(Path dir, int offset) {
        if (!Files.isDirectory(dir))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Directory must exist");
        this.dir = dir;
        this.offset = offset;
    }

    // Only a class and not a record because this is non-static (to access offset).
    public class Filename implements Comparable<Filename> {
        public final Path file;
        private final Matcher matcher;
        public final boolean matches;
        public final Integer id;

        private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
            """
            (?x)      # Verbose
            (?<stem>
                .*?   # Filename stem, lazy
            )
            (?<id>
               -?     # Optional negative
               \\d+   # Digits to be incremented, greedy
            )
            (?<ext>
                \\.     # Literal dot before extension
                [^.]*?  # Extension (non-dot), lazy
            )
            """
        );

        public Filename(Path file) {
            this.file = file;
            matcher = pattern.matcher(file.toString());
            matches = matcher.matches();
            id = matches? Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("id")): null;
        }

        public boolean isMatch() { return matches; }

        public Path increment() {
            String sub = "${stem}%d${ext}".formatted(id + offset);
            return Path.of(matcher.replaceFirst(sub));
        }

        public void rename() throws IOException {
            Files.move(file, increment());
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Filename other) {
            int c = Integer.compare(id, other.id);
            return offset > 0? -c: c;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return A stream of filenames that match the ID pattern; this cannot be used
     * for renaming because it stays lazy and does not include a deconflict sort.
     * @throws IOException If Files.list() fails.
     */
    public Stream<Filename> matchingFiles() throws IOException {
        return Files.list(dir)
            .map(Filename::new)
            .filter(Filename::isMatch);
    }

    /**
     * @return A list of Filenames sorted in rename order.
     * This materializes to a list because Stream::sorted materializes internally anyway.
     * @throws IOException If Files.list() fails.
     */
    public List<Filename> sortedFiles() throws IOException {
        List<Filename> names = matchingFiles().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.sort(names);
        return names;
    }

    public void rename(int offset) throws IOException {
        for (Filename name: sortedFiles())
            name.rename();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a tool to create `regex definitions that have comments and named groups.` :) ?

Comment: "Don't force a match, increment and rename all in one go." ... You can't rename one file (for example "5.txt" to "1.txt") when there is already a file with the target name ("1.txt"), without sorting the files first.

Comment: @Tobias321If that was your reason for sorting, it isn't enough to prevent filename clashes. Think: you allow negative offsets but don't match on hyphens in the ID.

Comment: @SRJ The tool is.. your fingers? Your keyboard? I don't understand the question.